# Where downloads folder should be placed in CodeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Where should I place my downloads files?

These should not be accessible to public.
But should be accessible to registered users.

My directory structure is as follows.

> -application
>   -system
>   -downloads
>   ---abc.7z
>   -index.php

As it can be seen that downloads are directly accessible to user through following.

`127.0.0.1/CI/downloads/abc.7z`

but to make it restricted I added  `.htaccess` with following directive

`Deny from all`

Its protected from public access now but I cannot access it from views which I was doing earlier as mentioned below.
`<a href="<?php echo base_url().'/downloads/abc.7z' ?>">click here to download</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the file available for download only for registered users, you can hide the actual filename from user.

1. Maintain a table to map a keyword(unique) and actual filename.
2. Provide a link that points a controller method with parameter as keyword of the file (do not explicitly display filename).
3. Read the file as per mapping and change filename to a random key (eg. session id) and then provide as download.